# Help link doesn't appear in module page

Tags: hooks

What do I have to do to show help link in module menu?

My code looks like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_help().
 */
function mymodule_help($path, $arg) {
  if ($path == 'admin/help#mymodule') {
    $output = '<h3>' . t('About') . '</h3>';
    $output .= '<p>' . t('descripton.') . '</p>';
    return $output;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you enabled the module?

Comment: Module enabled and caches flushed ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to the help link appear on the module page (`admin/modules`), you should have both the core Help module and your module enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It is advised to clear cache after implementation of any hook. Just clear your cache and it will show up.

You can also clear cache by drush command "drush cc all".

Answer (score 0):

/**
 * Implements hook_help().
 */

function mymodule_help($path, $arg) {

switch ($path) {

```
case 'admin/help#mymodule':
$output = '<h3>' . t('About') . '</h3>';
$output .= '<p>' . t('descripton.') . '</p>';
return $output;
```

}

}

Hope this will resolve your problem.